# Из контролера во View передать ccылку?

Tags: php, html, laravel, view, controller

```
foreach($data as $row)
            {

                $output .= "<td><a href="{{route('tag',[$row->id])}}">". $row->tag_name ."</a></td> ";
            }
```

это все в контроллере и ссылка не работает правильно, как изменить в Laravel?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

fetch_customer_data();

function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
{
  $.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
    method:'GET',
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
      $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
    }
  })
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var query = $(this).val();
  fetch_customer_data(query);
});});
```

js код

Comment: Что Вы передаёте во View? Покажите вызов вьюшки

Comment: @Confireus во View        $data = array(
                'table_data'  => $output,
                'total_data'  => $total_row
            );

            echo json_encode($data); там я это ловлю через ajax

Comment: ну так может покажете свой js код ?

Comment: @madfan41k уже добавлено выше

Comment: ну с js все верно, единственное что вы вызываете fetch_customer_data(); перед тем как js увидел что этот метод существует. и я уточню вопрос, что значит "ссылка не работает" ?

Comment: @madfan41k <a href="{{route('tag',[$row->id])}}">" эта ссылка неправильно формируется в контроллере и потом когда выводится на странице не работает, как правильно передать роут?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
    $output .= "<td><a href='".route('tag',['tag'=>$row->id])."'>". $row->tag_name ."</a></td> ";
}
```

Ну что бы более детальньнее было, нужно посмотреть ваши роуты

Comment: Route::get('tag/{tag}','TagsSearchPage@index')->name('tagpage');
    Route::get('/live_search', 'LiveSearch@index')->name('live_search');
Route::get('/live_search/action', 'LiveSearch@action')->name('live_search.action');
но теперь , когда добавляется ссылка аjax совершенно ничего не возвращает, запрос в бд идет, а вывода результата на страницу  нету

Comment: ну это вы уже сами дебажте, в коде который вы привели я ошибок не наблюдаю

Comment: сделайте в ajax методе "success" console.log(data) и посмотрите что вам возвращает php